# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content

Tags: c#, json, json.net, monogame

I am writing a monogame game and I need to send data about all 4 players (including data from portals, bullets, and so on) + status 
My class to deserialize:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace CounterPortal_2D.Classes
{
    public enum SessionStatus
    {
        StartGame, EndGame, StateUpdate, WaitingForPlayers
    }
    public class SessionInstance
    {
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public SessionStatus status = SessionStatus.WaitingForPlayers;

        [JsonProperty("players")]
        public List<Player> players;

        [JsonProperty("seed")]
        public int seed;

        public string Serialize()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
        
        public void Deserialize(string json)
        {
            SessionInstance nm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionInstance>(json);
            status = nm.status;
            players = nm.players;
            seed = nm.seed;
        } 
    }
}
```

Player class:

```cs
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

namespace CounterPortalServer.Classes
{
    public enum PlayerStatus
    {
        Ready, NotReady, Playing
    }
    public class Player
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id;

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public PlayerStatus status = PlayerStatus.NotReady;

        [JsonProperty("position")]
        public Vector2 position = new Vector2(100, 100);

        [JsonProperty("rotation")]
        public float rotation = 0;

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name;

        [JsonProperty("score")]
        public int score;

        [JsonProperty("isAlive")]
        public bool isAlive;

        [JsonProperty("portals")]
        private List<Portal> portals = new List<Portal>();

        [JsonProperty("bullets")]
        private List<Bullet> bullets = new List<Bullet>();

        [JsonIgnore]
        public Socket ClientSocket;
        

        public Player()
        {
            
        }

        public string Serialize()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }

        public void Deserialize(string json)
        {
            Player player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(json);
            position = player.position;
            name = player.name;
            score = player.score;
            isAlive = player.isAlive;
            portals = player.portals;
            bullets = player.bullets;
            score = player.score;
            Id = player.Id;
            status = player.status;
        }
    }
}
```

Json string:
`"{\"status\":2,\"players\":[{\"id\":\"c2162696-3c32-45f9-a22d-cd1b53cedc09\",\"status\":1,\"position\":\"100, 100\",\"rotation\":0.0,\"name\":null,\"score\":0,\"isAlive\":true,\"portals\":[{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"},{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"}],\"bullets\":[]},{\"id\":\"3e80797a-ea6d-45aa-87a8-da8f8d490f41\",\"status\":1,\"position\":\"100, 100\",\"rotation\":0.0,\"name\":null,\"score\":0,\"isAlive\":true,\"portals\":[{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"},{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"}],\"bullets\":[]},{\"id\":\"b72902d9-9cf1-4550-aad2-513bb7a3a181\",\"status\":1,\"position\":\"100, 100\",\"rotation\":0.0,\"name\":null,\"score\":0,\"isAlive\":true,\"portals\":[{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"},{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"}],\"bullets\":[]},{\"id\":\"f3b96040-c501-4333-b53e-bca5a5e825dc\",\"status\":1,\"position\":\"100, 100\",\"rotation\":0.0,\"name\":null,\"score\":0,\"isAlive\":true,\"portals\":[{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"},{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"}],\"bullets\":[]}],\"seed\":1502391845}{\"status\":2,\"players\":[{\"id\":\"c2162696-3c32-45f9-a22d-cd1b53cedc09\",\"status\":1,\"position\":\"100, 100\",\"rotation\":0.0,\"name\":null,\"score\":0,\"isAlive\":true,\"portals\":[{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"},{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"}],\"bullets\":[]},{\"id\":\"3e80797a-ea6d-45aa-87a8-da8f8d490f41\",\"status\":1,\"position\":\"100, 100\",\"rotation\":0.0,\"name\":null,\"score\":0,\"isAlive\":true,\"portals\":[{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"},{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"}],\"bullets\":[]},{\"id\":\"b72902d9-9cf1-4550-aad2-513bb7a3a181\",\"status\":1,\"position\":\"100, 100\",\"rotation\":0.0,\"name\":null,\"score\":0,\"isAlive\":true,\"portals\":[{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"},{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"}],\"bullets\":[]},{\"id\":\"f3b96040-c501-4333-b53e-bca5a5e825dc\",\"status\":1,\"position\":\"100, 100\",\"rotation\":0.0,\"name\":null,\"score\":0,\"isAlive\":true,\"portals\":[{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"},{\"position\":\"-1000, -1000\"}],\"bullets\":[]}],\"seed\":1502391845}"`
in end of string there is many `\0` symbols
I Don't know why there is really many `\0`. 
Visual Studio hits: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 1, position 890.'`
JSON is sent from the server via a TCP socket. Classes in server and client are same.
The bug happens all the time, no matter what I do. What can be done about it?

Comment: Show us the code, where the message is received. My suspicion is that you do not cap a buffer at the correct index or not at all before converting it to string data.

Comment: @Fildor ```                    SessionInstance session = new SessionInstance();
                    byte[] data = new byte[4096];
                    socket.Receive(data);
                    string json = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                    session.Deserialize(json);```

Comment: Please, add it to the question, by [edit]ing it.

Comment: But from this I can already see: You stringify the whole buffer, but did you receive _exactly_ 4096 bytes? Especially in the last read ? I guess not. Actually I am pretty sure, you'll have instances where bytes_received is < 4096. In that case, you need to only process the first X amount of bytes in the buffer, where X is the amount of bytes the receive method tells you it actually received.

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about doing this